# Custom NSView inside a column of a NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

I am using a view-based `NSTableView` with only one column.
I have the following code, which returns an `NSView` with two `NSTextField`s:

```
- (id) tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {

  NSView *v = [[NSView alloc] init];

  NSTextField *t1 = [[NSTextField alloc] init];
  [t1 setStringValue:@"test1"];

  NSTextField *t2 = [[NSTextField alloc] init];
  [t1 setStringValue:@"test2"];

  [v addSubview:t1];
  [v addSubview:t2];

  return v;
}
```

It seems that nothing happens, even if this code gets executed. I am not using the column identifier, I just want to return a custom view as a row.

This is the result:

[image: Table rows]

What am I doing wrong?

This view will be very custom and large, so I cannot rely on Apple's "default" cell views.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**View-based** is a different than **cell-based**.

All that is different is replacing the "id" return value to "NSView".

Change this:

```
- (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item
```

To this:

```
- (NSView *)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item
```

This is given the assumption you are running 10.7, and you are actually going to return an NSView.

Comment: Hello! If I use `- (NSView *)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item` instead of  `- (id) tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row`, the function does not get executed. Did I forgot to change something in IB or in code? The table view is set to view-based.

Comment: Check my other answer. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

A few things to check:

- Does your `NSTableView` have its delegate set to the class that
  implements the `NSTableViewDelegate` protocol? (I ask because
  `tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:` is a delegate method whereas the
  `tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:` is a data source method.)
- Are there any bindings that are set in IB? Check mainly for bindings
  to the `NSTableView` content binding and to the provided view's
  subviews (usually the text field.)
- Do you implement the `numberOfRowsInTableView:` method from the
  `NSTableViewDataSource` protocol and does it return a nonzero integer?

Finally, you might have a look at the *Table View Programming Guide* chapter on "*[Populating View-Based Table Views Programmatically](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/PopulatingView-TablesProgrammatically/PopulatingView-TablesProgrammatically.html)*" in the documentation.